# Disabling/Enabling a button through button click

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am displaying SQL data in rows and each row contains "Add To Zip" Button. The button for each row is enabled. I want to disable the current row's button on click. I later want to re-enable these disabled buttons through another button in a different php file. How do I achieve this?
Also, please do not point to SQL injection, I have used login details to check if the correct credentials are added or not and I will be only posting the code that I think is relevant to this question.

FetchData.php

```
...
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '<h4 align = "center">Search Result</h4>';
 $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class = "table table bordered">
                   <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>                                 
                    </tr>';
                    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
                
        $output .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToPdf(\''.$row["ID"].'\', this)"><i class="fa fa-pdf" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Add to Zip</button></td>
                </tr>
            ';
    }
    echo $output;
    
}
...
```

AddToZip.php

```
...
...
$sql = "INSERT INTO Zip (ID)
VALUES ('$id')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

header("Refresh: 0");
...
...
```

EDIT:
I am using AJAX to display the fetched values from `FetchData.php`

Index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>LiveData</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Live Data Search</h2><br />
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
     <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by ID" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    
   </div>

   <br />
   <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var txt = $(this).val();
        if(txt != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"FetchData.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {search:txt},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
       });

});

    var addToPdf = function(id, btn) {
    $.get({
        url:"AddToZip.php?id=" + id,
        success: function(data) {
            btn.disabled = true;
            
        }
    });
  };

</script>

...
...
```

Comment: @Dharman like I have mentioned in my question, I have taken steps to avoid SQL injections, just that I did not post that code since its irrelevant to my question.

Comment: What steps? I see you are using `query` for an `INSERT` query. If you find not want us to point SQL injection then you should have shown us the code where you do it with prepared statements. We need to see the real example not some made-up code.

Comment: @Dharman yes sorry, I will change the second php to use MySQLi, it is just that it is not complete. But in the first php I have taken steps to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your HTML markup. I.e. you have a `<button>` tag inside an anchor `<a>` tag which is technically incorrect. However, you most likely have some Bootstrap styling on the button tag and are only using the anchor to action the AddToZip.php call right?

If that's the case, I would rather strip out the `<a>` tag and use an onclick method on the `<button>`. An example:

Replace

```
<td><a href="AddToZip.php?id='.$row["ID"].'" target="target"><button  id="pdf" name="AddToZip" action="" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pdf"" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Add to Zip</button></a></td>
<iframe style="display:none;" name="target"></iframe>
```

With

```
<td><button id="pdf" name="AddToZip" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById(\'frame-x\').src=\'AddToZip.php?id='.$row["ID"].'\'; this.disabled = true;"><i class="fa fa-pdf" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Add to Zip</button></td>
<iframe style="display:none;" name="target" id="frame-x"></iframe>
```

---

#### To be clear

This is not an ideal solution, just a quick fix to achieve what the OP asked for help with. To the OP, I highly recommend using an Ajax call of sorts to communicate to the back-end.

I suggest looking into [jQuery's AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) API

---

#### Update after OP updated Question

So now that I see you are using jQuery AJAX calls, add a function to your script section:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
};


var addToPdf = function(id, btn) {
    $.get({
        url:"AddToZip.php?id=" + id,
        success: function(data) {
            btn.disabled = true;
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

Then change your markup to this (remove the iframe as well):

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToPdf(\''.$row["ID"].'\', this)"><i class="fa fa-pdf" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Add to Zip</button></td>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am using Bootstrap CSS. I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @Saif take a read to my last note on recommending AJAX

Comment: Actually i am using AJAX in the webpage. It acts like a search bar and the results from this php displays onto the search bar. Perhaps I can re-enable the button through that?

Comment: You should probably use DOM markup on the page from PHP to serve the initial page state (i.e. whichever buttons should be en/disabled) and then rely on jQuery from there on to maintain the state represented by any Ajax calls made. That way if you reload the page manually, there should be no difference

Comment: I have updated my code where I display the values. This is basically the display page.

Comment: Thank you for this code, I have successfully been able to disable it. Now I have to figure out how to re-enable it from another php file when clicked on a button. Also, when i refresh the page or re-enter data in the search bar, the button is re-enabled. I guess i must use a session here to keep the clicked button disabled?

Comment: I tried the AJAX solution but unfortunately the button is not getting disabled. I think the function is not getting called.

Comment: When i inspected the webpage, it shows 404 not found.

Comment: In the above solution, the button is only disabled on success, and a 404 result would not resolve as a success. 404 would indicate that the path to `AddToZip.php` might be wrong, check that first and try again - The AJAX path in `url` is relative to the page location unless you have a `<base>` tag in the head

Comment: I could call other phps under the AJAX code but only this is causing the problem. I have updated my code with your solution. Am I doing something wrong here with the brackets closing?

Comment: i tired to add the call function inside the $(document).ready(function() and the error i got that time was ```Uncaught ReferenceError: addToPdf is not defined  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick```.

Comment: The ‘addToPdf’ function shouldn’t be defined inside your document.ready block. Move it outside rather, as with my solution, it is declared after your document.ready. When you say it’s causing the problem, what do you mean? Is there an error message?

Comment: So when I tried to add addToPdf outside the document.ready block and even gave full path to the URL, then the error is ```WEBSITENAME/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: Ah found the solution. Instead of using $.get, we must use $.ajax.

Comment: If you use $.ajax instead of $.get, you must include the request type in the options I.e. type: “get”